# Querying BigQuery table in AI platform notebooks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-training

I'm stuck in using a query into my jupyter notebook of gcp.
The query work fine in Bigquery when I run it there (see pic below)

[image: bigquery]

When I run it in my notebook using this code.

```
query = """SELECT *, FROM [kaggle-competition-datasets:geotab_intersection_congestion.train] LIMIT 4"""
import google.datalab.bigquery as bq
train = bq.Query(query).execute().result().to_dataframe()
```

I get this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/datalab/bigquery/_query.py in execute_async(self, output_options, sampling, context, query_params)
    278       try:
--> 279         destination = query_result['configuration']['query']['destinationTable']
    280         table_name = (destination['projectId'], destination['datasetId'], destination['tableId'])

KeyError: 'destinationTable'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-85e1ffdadde6> in <module>
      1 query = """SELECT *, FROM [kaggle-competition-datasets:geotab_intersection_congestion.train] LIMIT 4"""
      2 import google.datalab.bigquery as bq
----> 3 train = bq.Query(query).execute().result().to_dataframe()

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/datalab/bigquery/_query.py in execute(self, output_options, sampling, context, query_params)
    337     """
    338     return self.execute_async(output_options, sampling=sampling, context=context,
--> 339                               query_params=query_params).wait()
    340 
    341   @staticmethod

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/datalab/bigquery/_query.py in execute_async(self, output_options, sampling, context, query_params)
    281       except KeyError:
    282         # The query was in error
--> 283         raise Exception(_utils.format_query_errors(query_result['status']['errors']))
    284 
    285     execute_job = _query_job.QueryJob(job_id, table_name, sql, context=context)

Exception: invalidQuery: Syntax error: Unexpected "[" at [1:16]. If this is a table identifier, escape the name with `, e.g. `table.name` rather than [table.name].
```

Of course I modified the query as suggested by the traceback but nothing works. What the problem does notebooks in gcp access in different manner in bigquery table??

Comment: The old BigQuery UI defaults to the Legacy SQL dialect. For the Standard SQL one you have to use a different table reference ``(`kaggle-competition-datasets.geotab_intersection_congestion.train`)``

Comment: Thanks, I’m using the new GUI. The code worked borh in new gui and old one.

Comment: Yes, sorry, anyway the query is in Legacy SQL. You can either use Standard SQL in the notebook (recommended) or switch to Legacy SQL. You can see here how I get the same error and fix it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CvsF.png

Comment: I’m ll what you mentioned

Comment: I used this single quote ` yesterday night also but it threw another error.

Comment: And what does the new error say? If it is `Exception: invalid: Project name needs to be separated by dot from dataset name, not by colon in table name ...` that's because you also need to change the `:` separator for a `.` as seen in my previous image and comment

Comment: That’s kind of error it waz yesterday. Sorry I’m out of home. Need to rename it so.

Comment: Yes the error I get, `Exception: invalid: Project name needs to be separated by dot from dataset name, not by colon in table name "kaggle-competition-datasets:geotab_intersection_congestion.train".`
 So I crated another dataset in bigquery GUI then imported table there and load them on notebook. As public dataset I do not have  right to change the name.
Thanks it's ok now.